# How to test whether a correlation is equal to 1?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, correlation, statistical-significance, confidence-interval

I am interested in an inferential test available in R which tests whether Pearson's $r = 1$ instead of whether $r = 0$. It would be good if the test allowed the correlation matrix and number of participants as input variables.

Comment: Can you clarify your situation?  Why are you wondering if the correlation is 1?  As @eric_kernfeld notes, this may not be what you really need.

Comment: If the correlation disattenuated for the reliability of each variable equals 1 this would mean that the correlated processes have a common mechanism which operates behind them. My hypothesis was that processes are somewhat specific relative to each other. So H0 : r = 1 and H1: r < 1. This is why I needed to test whether H0 is true.

Comment: It sounds like you have in mind a model of the form $(x_i,y_i)=(u_i, \alpha+\beta u_i)+(\delta_i,\epsilon_i)$ where $u_i$ is a random variable and $(\delta_i,\epsilon_i)$ is an error ("disattenuation"?) independent of $u_i$ and you want to compare that to some alternative model involving a more complicated relationship.

Comment: In which case (following @whuber), testing for $(\alpha, \beta) = (0,1)$ (given scaled $x,y$) _might_ reduce to testing correlation?

Comment: @Nutle No, because this model is one of *perfect* (underlying) correlation no matter what the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ might be.  A possible alternative hypothesis, for instance, could be $(x_i,y_i)=(u_i,\alpha+\beta_1u_i+\beta_2u_i^2)+(\delta_i,\epsilon_i).$ Testing $H_0:\beta_2=0$ is a test of perfect correlation. This is one of many possible ways of framing the problem.

Comment: @whuber: Actually, I have calculated a correlation between two variables. Following, split-half reliabilities were calculated for both of them, and the observed correlation was disattenuated for the error due to imperfect reliabilities. Now, I need to "test" whether the disattenuated correlation is different from identity, that is 1.

Comment: As far as I follow the thread, even after disattenuation, there is likely to be some variability in the data.  As noted in some responses, unless the sample *r* is precisely 1, the confidence interval for *rho* will not include 1, if calculated by *Z* transformation.  If you calculate the confidence interval by percentile bootstrap, there are cases where an *r* less than 1 will include 1 in the confidence interval, but you need very specific (probably artificial) conditions of sample size and values of the data to get this result.

Comment: *Are you really sure you want an *H0* of *rho = 1*?  This would seem to imply both that the data are perfectly correlated *and* that there is no residual error in the values.  Perhaps you want a linear regression, and test if *beta* is 1?  Or maybe you just want to test if *rho* is 0? Maybe you can give an example data set for which you would want to reject *H0* and one for which you would not want to reject *H0*.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I would argue that there is not any testing to do. If the sample correlation is not 1, then you reject $H_0: \rho=1$ with certainty.

Having a correlation of 1 means that the points cannot deviate from a diagonal line the way that they can when $\vert \rho \vert < 1$.

**EDIT**

```
set.seed(2019)
x <- rexp(1000)
y <- 3*x
plot(x,y)
V <- rep(NA,10000)
for (i in 1:length(V)){

  print(i)
  idx <- sample(seq(1,length(x),1),replace=T)
  V[i] <- cor(x[idx],y[idx])
}
summary(V)
```

With the points of the scatterplot locked to the diagonal line $y=3x$, every single sample correlation is 1. You can try this out with other distributions and sample sizes.

Where this gets interesting---and I'm not completely sure of the math at the population level---is when I set a Gaussian copula to have a parameter of 1.

```
library(copula)
set.seed(2019)
gc <-ellipCopula("normal", param = 1, dim = 2)#, dispstr = "un")
norm_exp <- mvdc(gc,c("norm","exp"),list(list(mean=0,sd=1),list(rate=1))) 
V <- rep(NA,10000)
for (i in 1:length(V)){
  print(i)
  D_ne <- rMvdc(1000, norm_exp) 
  x <- D_ne[,1]
  y <- D_ne[,2]
  V[i] <- cor(x[idx],y[idx])
}
plot(x,y)
summary(V)
```

I still don't think this relationship gives a population Pearson correlation of 1 (the relationship is perfectly monotonic but not linear), but this result surprised me. I expected another plot of a straight line.

To defend my assertion that the population Pearson correlation is not 1, I refer to theorem 4.5.7 on pg. 172 of the second edition of Casella & Berger's *Statistial Inference*: "$\vert \rho_{XY}\vert=1$ if and only if there exist numbers $a\ne0$ and $b$ such that $P(Y = aX+b)=1$." Since the relationship between my $X$ (the normal variable) and $Y$ (exponential) is nonlinear, there can be no such $a$ and $b$.

Casella, George, and Roger L. Berger. Statistical Inference. 2nd ed., Cengage Learning & Wadsworth, 2002.

Comment: This is such a simple (and correct) answer that it makes me wonder whether that's really what OP needed to ask...

Comment: Surely if the true "population" correlation coefficient $\rho$ was $1$, by sampling error you can still get a sample where the points are not in perfect alignment with the population assumption and hence $r < 1$ even though $\rho=1$.

Comment: @PaulHewson The points are locked to some diagonal line. Try this out with some software. I’ll edit my answer to include my own code showing this.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Fisher Z-transform is one way of doing this (usually used for confidence intervals), bootstrapping would be another.
Here's a brief article for Fisher Z transform for Pearson Product Moment Correlation Coefficient https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/fisher-z/

Comment: This should be equivalent to computing the confidence interval for the correlation coefficient and check whether it includes 1. I wonder whether for the upper limit of the interval a $2\alpha$ confidence level should be used, because this is only a one-sided problem. Side note: the function *CIr* in the R package *psychometric* implements the confidence interval computation. An easier to follow reference than the above site is https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/PASS/Confidence_Intervals_for_Pearsons_Correlation.pdf

Comment: It is impossible for the upper limit of confidence for the Fisher Z transform ever to overlap $1,$ because $1$ corresponds to an infinite value of $Z.$  Thus this test is just a waste of effort.  No amount of bootstrapping will produce an infinite upper limit, either.