# Significance test if R-squared ($R^2$) is significantly different from 1 (or some number very close to 1)

Tags: regression, correlation, statistical-significance, r-squared, f-test

I am trying to find a way to test if a R-squared value that is high (>90%, on a small sample of c30 observations) is not significantly different from 1 (or at least from a number very close to 1, 0.999 say).

Equivalently, I would be happy to find a way to test if a sample correlation is not significantly different from 1.

The context is the relationship between the financial returns of two similar assets that *should* behave identically but don't quite. So I want to check if, given the small sample, they do not behave significantly differently.

I have digged around hypothesis testing on $R^2$ and correlation without finding anything that fits.

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: One thought I had was to use the variance of the residuals - to see what is the lower bound of the confidence interval (using a chi-squared test) of this variance. This would then yield an upper bound for the R2. Not sure if this is the correct approach though...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check for a correlation of $1$, there is no statistical test to run. A correlation of $1$ means that the variables move together perfectly (and linearly). Empirically (in data), there can not be any deviation from a perfect linear relationship. Therefore, if the empirical correlation is not exactly $1$, the true correlation is not exactly $1$, and you know this with certainty.

[This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/438952/247274) of mine is probably a duplicate.